Should the establishment of the Covenant between Israel and YHWH be understood in the context of the Exile of Israel’s elites?
Should the establishment of the Covenant between the Israelites and YHWH be understood in the context of the exile of Israel and Judah’s elites? My understanding is that, prior to the establishment of the aforementioned Covenant, the Israelites and other Levantine Semitic peoples considered the world through the lens of a covenant between their respective gods and their rulers. However, after the ruling elites of the Kingdoms of Israel and Judah had been taken into captivity, the Israelite people were forced to reevaluate their relationship to their god YHWH, this reevaluation leading to  the concept of the Covenant between YHWH and the Israelites. Am I mistaken in this regard? Understand that I am a layman and am simply going off of my limited understanding of Biblical history and the evolution of YHWH within Israelite religion.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. Without a scripture to analyze, I am afraid your question risks being closed. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

I think the OP is indeed mistaken, whether one looks at the question with the assumption that the Torah was written by Moses or the assumption that most of it was written much later.
From the viewpoint that the Torah was written by Moses, the covenant between Yahweh and his people was instituted at Sinai. Exodus 19:

Thus shalt thou say to the house of Jacob, and tell the children of
Israel;  4 Ye have seen what I did unto the Egyptians, and how I bare you on
eagles' wings, and brought you unto myself.
5 Now therefore, if ye will obey my voice indeed, and keep my
covenant, then ye shall be a peculiar treasure unto me above all
people: for all the earth is mine:
6 And ye shall be unto me a kingdom of priests, and an holy nation.
These are the words which thou shalt speak unto the children of
Israel.
7 And Moses came and called for the elders of the people, and laid
before their faces all these words which the Lord commanded him.
8 And all the people answered together, and said, All that the Lord hath spoken we will do. And Moses returned the words of the people unto the Lord.

From the viewpoint that the Torah is a composite work written during the period of the Kings, the concept of the Covenant was still established well before the exile of either Israel of Judah. Even if one sees the Torah as having been completed after the Exile, the pre-exilic prophets often spoke of God's Covenant with his people. Hosea is a good example:
Hosea 6:

4 O Ephraim, what shall I do unto thee? O Judah, what shall I do unto
thee? for your goodness is as a morning cloud, and as the early dew it
goeth away. 5 Therefore have I hewed them by the prophets; I have
slain them by the words of my mouth: and thy judgments are as the
light that goeth forth. 6 For I desired mercy, and not sacrifice; and
the knowledge of God more than burnt offerings. 7 But they like men
have transgressed the covenant: there have they dealt treacherously
against me.

Conclusion: The covenant was made well before the exile of either Israel or Judah. Indeed, the biblical view - whether interpreted conservatively or critically - is that it was the violation of the Covenant that led to the exile.
